# when i write the toggle code in php block it not work

Tags: javascript, php, html

i am new in php. i just want to make a  button for  hide or un-hide the div
and i placed a code in php block
when i write code in php block.button not work properly;
when i code it outside the php block then it run.
why it not run in php block?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <?php
    echo"<button onclick='myFunction('confession13')'>Comment</button>
    <div id='confession13'>
    <p>hlo world</p>
    </div>";
    ?>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(p1) 
    {   
        console.log(p1);
        var x = document.getElementById(p1);
        if (x.style.display === "none") 
        {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } 
        else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: There's no space between 'echo' and the quote mark. Is this a typo? - Line 8

Comment: There is no need to use PHP block since it is only HTML and JavaScript.

Comment: no i m not want to run  js inside the php i just cll the js function inside php block

Comment: `<button onclick='myFunction('confession13')'>Comment</button>` use double quote around the parameter `<button onclick='myFunction(\"confession13\")'>Comment</button>`

Comment: thank you it's work properly

Comment: @AyushSahu you are welcome

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
     <button onclick='myFunction("confession13")'>Comment</button>
     <div id='confession13'>
     <p>hlo world</p>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction(p1) 
    {   
        console.log(p1);
        var x = document.getElementById(p1);
        if (x.style.display === "none") 
        {
            x.style.display = "block";
        } 
        else {
            x.style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```